# Failing to pass a tuple of initial parameters into scipy.optimize curve_fit

Tags: python, numpy, curve-fitting, scipy-optimize

I want to fit a sum of a polynomial and a sine to a data set.
I do not manage to pass a set of initial values for the coefficients (initial guess) into the function. I know that the asterisk (`*`) packs the variable.

I define the function

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from numpy.polynomial import Polynomial as P

def func(x,*A):
    A=A[0]  # to get the values only
    polynom=P(A[0:-3]) # all but the last three coefficients go into the polynomial
    sine=A[-3]*np.sin(A[-2]*(x-A[-1])) # the last three coefficients are for the sine
    y=polynom(x)+sine # sum up both
    return y
```

Let's take some test values:

```
P0=(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11)
```

The call of curve_fit fails:

```
coefs_scipy,pcov = sio.curve_fit(func,df.length,df.s,p0=P0)
```

where `df` is a pandas dataframe, the columns `length` and `s` containing the `x` and `y` values respectively.

The last error is

```
\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_16648/911748954.py in func(x, *A)
     29 def func(x,*A):
     30     A=A[0]  # to get the values only
---> 31     polynom=P(A[0:-3]) # all but the last three coefficients go into the polynomial
     32     sine=A[-3]*np.sin(A[-2]*(x-A[-1])) # the last three coefficients are for the sine
     33     y=polynom(x)+sine # sum up both

IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

indicating that it is not possible to extract `[0:-3]` from a scalar. Though `A` is not a scalar I assume

Astonishingly, when I just call the function with `func(1,P0)`
it works.

What is wrong?

Comment: What is `df.s` supposed to do? The second and third parameter of curve_fit should be the x and y data. So the call should include something like `sio.curve_fit(func,df['x'],df['y'],p0=P0)`

Comment: Please explain exactly what happens.  Do you get an error?  If so, include the complete traceback (i.e. the complete error message) in the question.  If there is no error but result is unexpected, show the result and explain what you expected.

Comment: @JakobStark `df.s` indicates the column with the name `s` in the dataframe. This is equivalent to `df['s']` , isn't it?

Comment: @WarrenWeckesser You're right. I have just edited my post, now showing the error message.

Comment: @Aneho yes you're right, I forgot about that. Seeing your error message, could you add a `print(A)` just before the `polynom=...` and tell us the output?

Comment: @Jakob Stark, I just tried what you did, and found out that indeed, A is a skalar: `A=1`. So I removed A=A[0] and now it works. On the other side, the direct call to the function `func[1,P0]` is no longer working. Somehow 'curve_fit' and the asterisk `*` in the function call seem to do the same.

Comment: I remember, that this behavior confused me before, but `curve_fit` internally calls the function like `func(x, *P0)` and not like you did as `func(x, P0)`. So you should just omit the `A=A[0]` line above, and it should work.

Comment: @JakobStark You should add your comment as an answer to the question if it solved OP's question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `curve_fit` function internally calls the target function like

```
func(x, *P0)
```

That means all the values in the P0 tuple are expanded into positional arguments to the function.

The function declaration

```
def func(x, *A):
    ...
```

collects all these positional arguments into A. So A is a tuple containing all the values and not a tuple of tuples.

To solve your problem, you should remove the

```
A=A[0]
```

line and change the direct call to the function to

```
func(1, *P0)
```

Comment: Thank you Jakob for summarizing your comment in this answer. I hope it will be useful to others.